# Solve: $169x \equiv 2267 \pmod{113}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

We have the linear cogruence:$169x \equiv 2267 \pmod{113}$

MY try:I tried manually,but it did not help.Thank you

Comment: By obvious mental arithmetic $2267\equiv7\pmod{113}$ and $169\equiv56\pmod{113}$. Does that help?

Comment: It's the same as 56x=7 mod 113.

Comment: 113 is prime so $56^{112} = 1$ so $1/56 = 56^{111} $.

Comment: Doh.  Didn't realize 56x2=112=-1.  So 56=-1/2.  So 56x(-14)=7.  -14=99.  56x99 = 112x48 +56=113x48-48+56=7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$169x\equiv 56x\equiv 2267\pmod{113}$$
Multiplying by -2 on both sides,
$$ -112x\equiv x\equiv 2267(-2)\equiv -14\pmod{113}$$
$$ x\equiv 99\pmod{113}$$